# ReSharper unit test runner gives Inconclusive to the outer class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, resharper

I have unit tests written using nUnit and tests are structured in a similar way as in [Phil Haack's post](http://haacked.com/archive/2012/01/02/structuring-unit-tests.aspx)

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class ClassToTest
    {
        [TestFixture]
        public class MethodToTest
        {
            [Test]
            public void ThrowsArgumentNullException_OnNullIndex()
            {
                ...
            }

            .. more tests for the method ..
        }

        [TestFixture]
        public class AnotherMethodToTest
        {
            [Test]
            public void ThrowsArgumentNullException_OnNullIndex()
            {
                ...
            }

            .. more tests for the method ..
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that I get *inconclusive* for the outer class that is used to group unit tests. I have tried with and without `[TestFixture]` on the outer and/or inner class, but it is always giving me Inconclusive.

I think the correct behavior should be to display unit test states from the inner class tests. Any ideas?

[image: Inconclusive is appearing for the outer class]

**Update**

One **ugly** fix seems to be creating a dummy test to the outer class and then put attribute `Ignore` on it.

```
[Test, Ignore]
public void DummyTest()
{
    Assert.IsTrue(true);
}
```

**Update 2**

Channs & Wayne are correct, outer class is just used for grouping, so changing from class to namespace is the best solution.

Comment: I had a simialar thing recently and it was simply because i had created an empty test. Have you get any empty tests?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your outer class only groups the related methods, suggest replacing it by a namespace.

```
namespace MyNamespace.ClassToTest
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly correct solution for the problem. You were slightly faster than Wayne, so I'll mark this as THE answer.

Comment: I had the same problem, but I need to use a base class.  Does this solution apply?

Comment: @thepaulpage - Sorry for the late reply. Have you found an answer? Do you mean that R# shows the test result as inconclusive for the base class when you have unit tests only for the child class?

Answer (score 6):

You probably have a [TestFixture] with no [Test]s -- maybe the outer class doesn't have any of its own tests? In which case, why not just use a namespace?

Comment: This would have driven me insane...luckily I stack-overflowed it!

Comment: @mcl's suggestion fixed the problem I had.  +1!

Answer (score 1):

just a guess, the attribute on the class causes your class to be handled as a testclass, but there are no test in the class it self causes our Inconclusive:

```
[TestFixture]     
public class ClassToTest
```